# Pulling last log on time in ps script showing blank field

Tags: powershell, report, multi-factor-authentication

I have been tasked with pulling a list of all MFA enabled/disabled accounts in our environment. I found a script and modified with with extra  fields I needed, one of them being Last Log On Time. I need this basically for to filter through the report to remove any type of service accounts/ external account ect. The code I have just outputs a blank field when exporting to the csv.

I've tried every variation of LastLogon I could find (time,date,ect)

```
$Report = @()
$i = 0
$Accounts = (Get-MsolUser -All | ? {$_.StrongAuthenticationMethods -ne $Null} | Sort DisplayName)
ForEach ($Account in $Accounts) {
   Write-Host "Processing" $Account.DisplayName
   $i++
   $Methods = $Account | Select -ExpandProperty StrongAuthenticationMethods
   $MFA = $Account | Select -ExpandProperty StrongAuthenticationUserDetails
   $State = $Account | Select -ExpandProperty StrongAuthenticationRequirements
   $Methods | ForEach { If ($_.IsDefault -eq $True) {$Method = $_.MethodType}}
   If ($State.State -ne $Null) {$MFAStatus = $State.State}
      Else {$MFAStatus = "Disabled"}
   $ReportLine = [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
       User      = $Account.DisplayName
       UPN       = $Account.UserPrincipalName
       Department = $Account.Department
       Office = $Account.Office
       LastLogon = $Account.LastLogon  
       MFAMethod = $Method
       MFAPhone  = $MFA.PhoneNumber
       MFAEmail  = $MFA.Email
       MFAStatus = $MFAStatus  }
   $Report += $ReportLine      }
Write-Host $i "accounts are MFA-enabled"

$Report | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation c:\temp\MFAUsers.CSV
```

Any help with exporting the last log on date would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test this, but I think you need `LastLogon = (Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity $Account.UserPrincipalName).LastLogonTime`.

As a sidenote, adding objects to an array is slow and there is an easier method of collecting the emitted objects into the `$Report` variable:

```
$mfaEnabled = 0
$Accounts = (Get-MsolUser -All | ? {$_.StrongAuthenticationMethods -ne $Null} | Sort DisplayName)
$Report = foreach ($Account in $Accounts) {
   Write-Host "Processing" $Account.DisplayName

   $Methods = $Account | Select -ExpandProperty StrongAuthenticationMethods
   $MFA     = $Account | Select -ExpandProperty StrongAuthenticationUserDetails
   $State   = $Account | Select -ExpandProperty StrongAuthenticationRequirements

   $Methods | ForEach-Object { If ($_.IsDefault -eq $True) {$Method = $_.MethodType}}
   If ($State.State) {$MFAStatus = $State.State} else {$MFAStatus = "Disabled"}

   # update the counter for MFA Enabled users
   if ($MFAStatus -eq 'Enabled') { $mfaEnabled++ }

   # just emit the PSObject here, it will be collected in the $Report variable.
   # also, no need to use [ordered] on [PSCustomObject]
   [PSCustomObject]@{
       User       = $Account.DisplayName
       UPN        = $Account.UserPrincipalName
       Department = $Account.Department
       Office     = $Account.Office
       LastLogon  = (Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity $Account.UserPrincipalName).LastLogonTime  
       MFAMethod  = $Method
       MFAPhone   = $MFA.PhoneNumber
       MFAEmail   = $MFA.Email
       MFAStatus  = $MFAStatus
    }
}

Write-Host  "$mfaEnabled accounts are MFA-enabled"

$Report | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation c:\temp\MFAUsers.CSV
```